# Workbook protect / unprotect wihtin a macro

Tags: excel, passwords

I'm developing a macro-enabled spreadsheet that will be used by a select group of semi-intelligent people (managers). I am complete except for one minor hiccup. I want the sheet to be read-only for their use and to require a password to open for editing for my use. Within the macro I have written, once they are complete with their actions the data they have entered is automatically saved on another tab they can not see, then the sheet is reset for further entries/interactions. Once they are done, they should be able to close the sheet without a save prompt as their data has already been saved.

Here is my paradox: I can not get the macro to save over the existing instance of this workbook. If I remove the workbook password within the macro, it saves the workbook without password protection. I have tried to:

1. `unprotect` the workbook, save it, then protect it again. Of course, the saved copy is not read/write protected.
2. `SaveAs` with the password for writing to it intact, but then I get an error message that the workbook already exists (yes, I have turned off error reporting). Researched a lot of places, can't find a solution.

Comment: "that will be used by a select group of semi-intelligent people (managers)", and you are "Really intelligent"???

Comment: How you will know that the user end editing??? May be you just need to protect the whole sheet less the cells where the user need to input all the data. Then a validation for that cells has the requiered info, then save the workbook without even unprotect it.

Comment: Why not add the password back with the macro?  Also, from what I've seen by searching around for various things, Excel's protection can be beaten pretty easily, especially if your managers are "semi-intelligent" (also, although you derided your managers, I'm going to guess they're smarter than you think).  Why though would your managers want to edit things after they're done? I'd think that they could just edit the workbook, and save. What's the real purpose of locking your workbook? "I want it to be read only for their use", not quite true since you want them to edit the workbook.

Comment: Given the use case you describe I'm also not sure that you need the workbook protected, just worksheets (and maybe not even all of those). Like BruceWayne asks, you need to precisely nail down what needs protecting (for my money the data is all that really matters, so worksheet is probably all you need). And actually you may not even need that, just set the worksheet you copy their data to to VeryHidden in the VBA editor and you should be fine (if they know how to undo that setting they'll be able to get around anything you throw at them anyway).